# Direct JQuery click events to two of same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, onclick, jquery-events

I have a web page which loads a slider/drawer. Inside the web page, I load an html div for the contents of the drawer for when the window is expanded, and another duplicate of it for when the window is collapsed in a small window like on a phone.

On the page is have a function like:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

The large button of

```
<div id="button">
 //button here
</div>
```

loads before the small version. So clicking the large one works and the `.click` event is triggered, but for the small one it isn't.

How can I get my `.click` function to observe the click event on the small drawer when it's clicked?

Comment: Can you show HTML for small button?  Are you using same id?  If so, that is a problem in that id's must be unique (you would need to use a class instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you are in need of a single function which handles click events from multiple elements.

I would not use IDs for the elements, but instead use a class to decorate the ones that need the functionality. Then using 'this', I can further modify the item that was clicked...

```
$('.myClickable').click(function(){
  $(this).someFunc();
});
```

Comment: Making button a class worked, however the addition of $(this) was not necessary but caused it to not work. So just making the element a class instead of an id worked. Thanks. I didn't realize there is a functional difference between id and class besides convention, is this true?

Comment: Yes, they are different. When used correctly, ID should be unique across the entire HTML document - use it for unique elements like Nav Bars, Document Areas, etc. Class is the way to go for assigning common styling and functionality across multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Use same class, different ids:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var foo=$(this).attr('id');
alert(foo);
});
```

html:

```
<div class="button" id="bar">
</div>

<div class="button" id="moo">
</div>
```